# How to run processing script on multiple frames in a folder

Tags: processing

Using processing I am trying to run a script that will process a folder full of frames.

The script is a combination of PixelSortFrames and SortThroughSeamCarving.

I am new to processing and what I want does not seems to be working. I would like the script to run back through and choose the following file in the folder to be processed. At the moment it stops at the end and does not return to start on next file (there are three other modules also involved).

Any help would be much appreciated. :(

```
/* ASDFPixelSort for video frames v1.0
Original ASDFPixelSort by Kim Asendorf <http://kimasendorf.com>
https://github.com/kimasendorf/ASDFPixelSort
Fork by dx <http://dequis.org> and chinatsu <http://360nosco.pe>


// Main configuration
String basedir = ".../Images/Seq_002"; // Specify the directory in which the frames are         located. Use forward slashes.
String fileext = ".jpg"; // Change to the format your images are in.
int resumeprocess = 0; // If you wish to resume a previously stopped process, change     this value.

boolean reverseIt = true;
boolean saveIt = true;

int mode = 2; // MODE: 0 = black, 1 = bright, 2 = white
int blackValue = -10000000;
int brightnessValue = -1;
int whiteValue = -6000000;
// -------

PImage img, original;
float[][] sums;
int bottomIndex = 0;
String[] filenames;
int row = 0;
int column = 0;
int i = 0;
java.io.File folder = new java.io.File(dataPath(basedir));
java.io.FilenameFilter extfilter = new java.io.FilenameFilter() {
  boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(fileext);
  }
};

void setup() {
  if (resumeprocess > 0) {i = resumeprocess - 1;frameCount = i;}

  size(1504, 1000); // Resolution of the frames. It's likely there's a better way of     doing this.. 
  filenames = folder.list(extfilter);
  size(1504, 1000);
  println("  " + width + " x " + height + " px");

  println("Creating buffer images...");
  PImage hImg = createImage(1504, 1000, RGB);
  PImage vImg = createImage(1504, 1000, RGB);

  // draw image and convert to grayscale
  if (i +1 > filenames.length) {println("Uh.. Done!"); System.exit(0);}
  img = loadImage(basedir+"/"+filenames[i]);
  original = loadImage(basedir+"/"+filenames[i]);
  image(img, 0, 0);
  filter(GRAY);
  img.loadPixels();    // updatePixels is in the 'runKernals'

  // run kernels to create "energy map"
  println("Running kernals on image...");
  runKernels(hImg, vImg);
  image(img, 0, 0);

  // sum pathways through the image
  println("Getting sums through image...");
  sums = getSumsThroughImage();

  image(img, 0, 0);
  loadPixels();

  // get start point (smallest value) - this is used to find the 
  // best seam (starting at the lowest energy)
  bottomIndex = width/2;
  // bottomIndex = findStartPoint(sums, 50);
  println("Bottom index: " + bottomIndex);

  // find the pathway with the lowest information
  int[] path = new int[height];
  path = findPath(bottomIndex, sums, path);

  for (int bi=0; bi<width; bi++) {

// get the pixels of the path from the original image
original.loadPixels();
color[] c = new color[path.length];               // create array of the seam's color     values
    for (int i=0; i<c.length; i++) {
  try {
    c[i] = original.pixels[i*width + path[i] + bi];      // set color array to values     from original image
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    // when we run out of pixels, just ignore
  }
}

println("  " + bi);

c = sort(c);                                      // sort (use better algorithm later)
if (reverseIt) {
  c = reverse(c);
}

    for (int i=0; i<c.length; i++) {
      try {
       original.pixels[i*width + path[i] + bi] = c[i];      // reverse! set the pixels     of the original from sorted array
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
        // when we run out of pixels, just ignore
      }
    }
    original.updatePixels();
  }
 // when done, update pixels to display
 updatePixels();

 // display the result!
 image(original, 0, 0);

  if (saveIt) {
   println("Saving file...");
   //filenames = stripFileExtension(filenames);
    save("results/SeamSort_" + filenames + ".tiff");
  }

  println("DONE!");
}

// strip file extension for saving and renaming
String stripFileExtension(String s) {
  s = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('/')+1, s.length());
  s = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('\\')+1, s.length());
  s = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf('.'));
  return s;
}
```

This code works by processing all images in the selected folder

```
String basedir = "D:/things/pixelsortframes"; // Specify the directory in which the     frames are located. Use forward slashes.
String fileext = ".png"; // Change to the format your images are in.
int resumeprocess = 0; // If you wish to resume a previously stopped process, change     this value.

int mode = 1; // MODE: 0 = black, 1 = bright, 2 = white
int blackValue = -10000000;
int brightnessValue = -1;
int whiteValue = -6000000;

PImage img;
String[] filenames;
int row = 0;
int column = 0;
int i = 0;
java.io.File folder = new java.io.File(dataPath(basedir));
java.io.FilenameFilter extfilter = new java.io.FilenameFilter() {
 boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(fileext);
  }
};

void setup() {
 if (resumeprocess > 0) {i = resumeprocess - 1;frameCount = i;}
  size(1920, 1080); // Resolution of the frames. It's likely there's a better way of      doing this.. 
  filenames = folder.list(extfilter);
 }

void draw() {
  if (i +1 > filenames.length) {println("Uh.. Done!"); System.exit(0);}
  row = 0;
  column = 0;
  img = loadImage(basedir+"/"+filenames[i]);
  image(img,0,0);
  while(column < width-1) {
    img.loadPixels(); 
   sortColumn();
   column++;
   img.updatePixels();
 }

 while(row < height-1) {
   img.loadPixels(); 
    sortRow();
    row++;
    img.updatePixels();
  }
  image(img,0,0);
  saveFrame(basedir+"/out/"+filenames[i]);
  println("Frames processed: "+frameCount+"/"+filenames.length);
  i++;
}
```

essentially I want to do the same thing only with a different image process but my code is not doing this to all with in the folder... just one file.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about what the `setup()` function does. It runs once, and *only* once, at the beginning of your code's execution. You don't have any looping structure for processing the other files, so it's no wonder that it only processes the first one. Perhaps wrap the entire thing in a for loop? It looks like you kind of thought about this, judging by the global variable `i`, but you never increment it to go to the next image and you overwrite its value in several for loops later anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My code is directly taken from this...following post

Comment: Problem solved, I just had to really think about what was happening in the code correctly, thanks.